# Ubuntu 22.04 wifi connection is lost every x minutes

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager, dns

A week or two ago my wifi started losing the connection every 10-20 minutes. As far as I am aware I did not do any updates or anything prior to this. I have tried all sorts of solutions found online, to no avail.

My quick fix has been to use my phone as a wifi-hotspot using the same wifi that errors on computer. This works, but obviously not a fix.

Looking at syslog, it seems to have something to do with DNS. I have tried changing the DNS to Google (8888/8844), changing powersave settings, but this did not help.

**Starting to get desperate. Hope someone can help?**

Here is a dump of some network config stuff:
https://gist.github.com/kingkong-cmd/da65b13844db26fbb3a3acf27056c600

My syslog looks like this when it happens. If i reconnect after this, it works again for x minutes before same happens.

```
Feb 27 21:40:59 [computer] systemd-resolved[30472]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
Feb 27 21:41:08 [computer] NetworkManager[668]: <info>  [1709066468.3896] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Feb 27 21:41:08 [computer]  dbus-daemon[667]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.9' (uid=0 pid=668 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Feb 27 21:41:08 [computer]  systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 27 21:41:08 [computer]  dbus-daemon[667]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb 27 21:41:08 [computer]  systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 27 21:41:09 [computer]  systemd-resolved[30472]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
Feb 27 21:41:18 [computer]  systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 27 21:41:40 [computer]  systemd-resolved[30472]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 8.8.4.4
```

Edit:
Also tried setting DNSSEC=no in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf ref:
https://superuser.com/questions/1676584/using-degraded-feature-set-tcp-instead-of-udp-for-dns-server

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1676584/using-degraded-feature-set-tcp-instead-of-udp-for-dns-server

Comment: @Esther Thanks, I already tried the suggestions in that post, setting DNSEC=no.

Comment: and then rebooted, I assume?

Comment: @Esther Yes, a million times unfortunately

Comment: Results from terminal for `iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Added it on top of my gist (while connected to the hotspot) https://gist.github.com/kingkong-cmd/da65b13844db26fbb3a3acf27056c600

Comment: A Mediatek mt7921 device, they aren't really good

Comment: @Jeremy31 It worked just fine up until a week ago. Any idea what may have happened?

Comment: WiFi disconnecting is not related to DNS. DNS is at a higher level. At the lower level, you would still be able to stay connected and ping gateway or 8.8.8.8 if DNS doesn't work.

Comment: try `sudo iw dev wlp1s0 set txpower fixed 20mBm`

Comment: @DanielT Yeah, well, it doesn't disconnect per se. It just hangs when the "Using degraded feature set.. for DNS" kicks in.

Comment: What is the output of the first few rounds of `ping 8.8.8.8` when it happens?

Comment: @DanielT Nothing. The connection stops working. I have to disconnect and connect again to get it working again. --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
40 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 39936ms

Comment: Then it's a WiFi not a DNS problem. Do you see anything incoming in Wireshark?

Comment: @DanielT Not familiar with wireshark or how to interpret, but I cannot see anything that sticks out. Can I look at logs other than syslog? nmcli monitor shows nothing.

Comment: The logs are `journalctl -b -0 -r -u NetworkManager -u wpa_supplicant` . If you can't trace packets with Wireshark, then I can only suggest trying a 23.10 LiveCD to know if newer firmware fixes it. Or a workaround could be a script to reconnect every 10 minutes

Comment: @DanielT Thanks, I'll monitor those logs and see if i can make some more sense of it. I just want it to work, so 23.10 is not an option. Unfortunately, back to windows is probably where I will go.

Comment: Can you also [edit] with `iwconfig`? If you're on 5GHz, move your router to 2.4 GHz to avoid radar

Comment: @DanielT Sure. I've tried all sorts of variations of isolating and disabling/enabling router options. I think it's just time to to throw in the towel and admit Linux is not for me.